# What is the logic of several <?php ?> in one file

Tags: php

I can’t find answer anywhere or just don’t get it.
So, I have HTML and PHP code combined in my PHP file. In books it’s written that the code in `<?php ?>` are executed on server only and html will display in browser. But I don’t understand THIS:

```
<?php if ($a = $b) { ?>
   <p>Text when condition is true</p>
<?php } else { ?>
   <p>Text when condition is false</p>
<?php } ?>
```

The above is working in browser but I don’t understand why it doesn't output error
or at least it should output both sentences.
For me it seems that the statement is broken into peaces and the only way when it should work is:

```
<?php 
if ($a = $b) 
{           
   echo "<p>Text when condition is true</p>"
} else { 
   echo "<p>Text when condition is false</p>"
}      
?>
```

What do I miss here?

Comment: This may help you understand the concept: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: You'll understand more when you have a string with lots of single and double quotation marks that you'd have to escape. It can look a lot better and be less prone to problems to use it as a templating engine. Of course, you're better off using something like Twig on top of PHP.

Comment: The question is actually about using PHP echo vs. spaghetti coding.

Comment: @Gohn67 Thanks a lot, I didn't get to that yet, now it's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the way it works. PHP is a templating language and you can play tricks like that.

A piece of HTML in between two PHP blocks is interpreted as "output these characters".

It's generally a good idea to keep this kind of intermixing of PHP and HTML to a minimum, though - any serious back-end code that goes beyond simple if/else structures or loops should be in a separate location.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear that I can do tricks like that. [The link to php manual - Alternative syntax for control structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Answer (score 1):

The former is useful when you need to output several html depending on the condition. Imagine you need to load a whole div with text. Doing with html is easier to handle. For small conditions like your example, the second example would make more sense.